# My code seems right but ajax response 500 error

Tags: php

This is the code I use on GoDaddy hosting server. With PHP5.6, It keep returning 500 error at `$stmt->get_result();`. Can anyone please help me find what I'm done wrong?

```
$tel=$_POST['tel'];
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare("select * from affeliate_db where tel=?");
$stmt->bind_param('i',$tel);
$stmt->execute();
$result=$stmt->get_result();
if($result->num_rows){
    echo "existed";
}else{
    echo "found usr";
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: check the logs to see what the error is

Comment: Thanks for the suggest, but I did before asking :(

Comment: So what are you saying, that the error log contains nothing about this?

Comment: Nope, nothing about db nor code error. Only ssl status from Let's Encrypt that it's working just fine. So what about my code, anything wrong?

Comment: Not syntactically, by the looks of it. Go and enable proper PHP error reporting then, or ask your hoster about the log file.

Comment: I moved these files onto another server. It works just fine! Will call GoDaddy, Thnx!

Comment: Verify that $tel is passed or check if it's isset and than assing a value. Fatal can be here. Secondly sanitize $tel before passing to SQL.

Comment: But in general setup XDebug

Comment: @VitaliProtosovitski The $tel returns correctly. I host on shared hosting. Don't know if they'll cost me again.